# Equivalence of toposes $\mathcal{E}/(X + Y) \simeq \mathcal{E}/X \times \mathcal{E}/Y$

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Notation: I write $A + B$ for the coproduct.

Nota bene: I have no idea if the pseudo-inverses I cooked up are the right ones, but I think those are the only ones you can define.

For $\mathcal{E}$ a topos, I am trying to prove that there is an equivalence $\mathcal{E}/(X + Y) \simeq \mathcal{E}/X \times \mathcal{E}/Y$.

Label the inclusions $X \xrightarrow{i} X + Y \xleftarrow{j} Y$ and define the functors $$\langle i^*, j^* \rangle: \mathcal{E}/(X + Y) \to \mathcal{E}/X \times \mathcal{E}/Y$$ ($i^*$ denotes taking the pullback over $i$) and

the functor $$+: \mathcal{E}/X \times \mathcal{E}/Y \to \mathcal{E}/(X + Y)$$

which sends $(a: A \to X, b: B \to Y)$ to $a + b: A + B \to X + Y$ and morphisms $(f, g): (a, b) \to (a', b')$ to $f + g: A + B \to A' + B'$.

The composition $\langle i^*, j^* \rangle \circ +$ is equal to the identity, I am having trouble proving $\circ + \langle i^*, j^* \rangle$ is isomorphic to the identity functor.

Comment: Can you do it for $Set$?

Comment: @Berci I think so. In Set we send $f: A \to X + Y$ to the $(\{(x, a) \in X \times A \ | \ f(a) = x\} \to X, \{(y, b) \in Y \times A \ | \ f(a) = y) \to Y)$ (the restricted projection maps) and then to $(X \times A)' \sqcup (Y \times A)' \to (X \times Y)$ (denoting ' for the subsets) which sends $(x, a)$ to $f(a) = x$  and $(y, a)$ to $f(a) = y$. So the isomorphism would be sending $(x, a)$ to $a$ and $(y, a)$ to $a$ with as inverse $\langle \pi_1 \circ f, \pi_2 \circ f \rangle$.

Comment: A sketch of the argument is here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/toposes+are+extensive

Comment: @KevinCarlson Is is true that any square where the top and bottom arrows are coproduct inclusions is a pullback in a Topos? I can show it is a pushout, and thus if the left down-arrow is mono, it is also a pullback, but does this work in general? This is what it says on nLab, extensive categories: 

In any commutative diagram
\array{x & \to & z & \leftarrow & y\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ a & \to & a+b & \leftarrow & b}

the two squares are pullbacks if and only if the top row is a coproduct diagram.

Comment: Link : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category, 
In section 2.3